# How to redirect the DNS for your domain's A record to the CNAME record

Tags: apache, redirect, dns

I understand that an A record should point to an IP address and a CNAME must point to another domain, e.g.

```
A           foo.com        100.0.0.1
CNAME       www.foo.com    foo.com
```

That way if a person tries to go to foo.com or www.foo.com both requests will go to the same server. And then our server can redirect foo.com to www.foo.com for standardization (particularly when SSL certificates are involved).

But is it possible for a DNS records to not have an A record, and instead to manage the simple domain with a CNAME record that points to another dynamic domain (instead of a fixed IP)? e.g.

```
CNAME        @                foo.gutensite.net
CNAME        www.foo.com      foo.gutensite.net
```

Both foo.com and www.foo.com would point to foo.gutensite.net.

## The Goal

We run a web hosting company, and we want to tell clients to point their domain DNS to a dynamic location (not a fixed IP address). We don't want to make them point to a specific IP address, because sometimes we need to change the server IP addresses as we adjust the infrastructure, e.g. spin up new servers, change hosting platforms, etc (FYI, We use Load Balancers, but sometimes we need to change the IP addresses as we put the client on a different cluster). However, that means making hundreds of clients update their DNS settings, something that is a nightmare for non-technical clients.

So if instead, we could just have them point their DNS to a dynamic location via a CNAME record to begin with, then we can change the DNS settings for them when we need to, e.g.

```
CNAME         www.foo.com        foo.gutensite.net
```

And we control `foo.gutensite.net` (our subdomain) to point to whatever server node they are hosted on (if we ever have to change it).

## A Hacky Solution

Since DNS doesn't appear to allow DNS records without an A record that is pointed to an IP address, we are considering a hacky solution. We could spin up a simple server that has a static IP address that never changes (it can be hosted anywhere). This servers sole job is to redirect any all traffic to the subdomain www.{DOMAIN}. We then tell clients to point their A record to this IP address, and anytime a visitor requests foo.com it will redirect to www.foo.com and at that point the correct CNAME record will take over.

I don't like this solution, because it's circumventing the purpose of the A record by throwing up a decoy that redirects to the www version. But it would work, and I can't think of any real downsides.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I really can't make any sense out of your question. Particularly this sentence seems to indicate some level of very basic misunderstanding: "Since DNS doesn't appear to allow DNS records without an A record that is pointed to an IP address, we are considering a hacky solution".

DNS is a database. It cares very little about the data stored in it. You're talking about web stuff, where DNS is used by browsers too translate from the names that humans use to the numbers that computers use. What number do you want to be returned when what name is looked up?

Comment: I do understand how DNS works. And although you **can** create database records that are broken, you obviously don't want to. Perhaps you could reread and try to understand my question a little more carefully. I'm wondering if there is a way to make a primary domain (e.g. foo.com) direct to a domain (e.g. foo.bar.com) instead of an IP address. I believe a DNS requires A records to point to an IP and there is no way to specify the basic domain via a CNAME. Since that appears to be the case, then are there any obvious problems with our hacky solution?